# Can two user level threads of same process can run simultaneously on multicore CPU?

Tags: operating-systems, multi-threaded

Can two user level threads of same process can run simultaneously on multi core CPU ?

Comment: Yes of course it can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually: Yes.

Assuming they do not block on a shared resource.
E.g. lock access to a single joystick, or try to lock a shared file, ...

---

A shared file might be more common than expected. E.g. locking a .ini file or a using temp file without using a proper random name.

Comment: what if they are cooperating threads and both request for a resource at same time ?

Comment: That is what [semaphores](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_%28programming%29) are for.  Only one tread will get the resource, the other will block until the first tread releases it.

Comment: yea i got but i have a couple of doubts                     1) What happens if you block a thread ie means if a down operation is unsuccessful , should that thread alone will go to blocking state or the entire process will also go to blocking state? 2)second thing is , it have multiple cores rite what if both will do a down operation simultaneously on a same semaphore .( ignore this doubt  if you find it very silly).

Comment: Multiple operations at the same time is a valid question.  

It was a big problem in the past and it is why we developed mutexes and semaphores. Even with these we needed to resort to tricks in case two processes tried to claim a resource at *precisely* the same time.  These days most CPU's have a few instructions which are guaranteed to be atomic. (E.g. the [test and set instruction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-and-set).)

Just how the CPU handles that when two core try this at precisely the same time is something you may need to ask the CPU designer.

Comment: It might be something as simple as giving the CPU with the lowest core number priority, but that is a guess and that may vary per CPU. As to blocking processes vs treads. I think it is safe to read this as 'block the thread' rather then block the process. Multi-threaded processes seems to be relative new (not in desing, but in actual usage) and I think it is safe that the writer just used “process” rather than “single threaded process or a specific tread”.

Comment: Can i clarify one thing like are you talking about user thread or kernel thread ? I asked about User level thread ?

Comment: For the CPU there is no difference between these two.